# How do I install dependencies for Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg, chainlink

trying to install yarn for my chainlink node. This is the error I'm getting. Any thoughts?

```
node -e "if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('Please use yarn to install dependencies\n\n')"
```

Comment: Can you please add more details? Like what command you ran to get this, how you got here, etc.

Comment: I am also having this exact problem. I set up my hardhat project and run npm install --save @chainlink/contracts, but it always fails with that message. Would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
yarn install
```

in the main node's folder?

Comment: no didn't work says error Command failed with exit code 137.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.